# Select from multiple tables even if one doesn't have any corresponding record

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-workbench

I have three tables: product, sale and purchase.

I need to get the **sum of sales** and the **sum of purchases** of the products.
Even if no sales were made, I need it to show the purchases and vice-versa.
Something like:

```
Product   | Sum of sales | Sum of purchases |
____________________________________________
product 1 | 10000        | 45000            |
product 2 | 20000        | 0 (or null)      |
product 3 | 0(or null)   | 20000            |
```

I've tried this, but it'll only return products that have both sales and purchases simultaneously:

```
select prod.name, sum(s.total), sum(p.total)
from product prod
inner join sale s on s.prod_id = prod.id
inner join purchase p on p.prod_id = prod.id
group by 1;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has a couple of issues. Firstly, because of the `INNER JOIN` it will (as you found) only return values for products which have both sales and purchases. This can be resolved by using `LEFT JOIN` (with an optional `COALESCE` to convert `null` values into `0`). The second problem is that you will get duplicate rows from your `JOIN` where there is more than one sale or purchase of a product. To work around that, you need to perform the aggregation in derived tables for sales and purchases:

```
SELECT pr.name,
       s.total AS sales,                    -- will show null if no sales
       COALESCE(p.total, 0) AS purchases    -- will show 0 if no purchases
FROM product pr
LEFT JOIN (SELECT prod_id, SUM(total) AS total
           FROM sale
           GROUP BY prod_id) s ON s.prod_id = pr.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT prod_id, SUM(total) AS total
           FROM purchase
           GROUP BY prod_id) p ON p.prod_id = pr.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been stuck on this problem for days.